Drawing latitudinal line on a sphere associated with a given angle of elevation
I am trying to create a function which would draw a unit cone, a unit sphere and an intersection between them as a dashed line where invisible and as a solid line where visible. So far I have only achieved the following. I do not manage to make the arcs sit exactly at the intersections.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{45}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{180}{-90}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering

 \tikzset{surface/.style={draw=blue!70!black, fill=blue!20!white, fill opacity=.6}}

 \newcommand{\coneback}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:225+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \newcommand{\conefront}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:-135+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1]
 \newcommand{\conewidth}{1.3}
 \newcommand{\coneheight}{2.5}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  
     \coneback[surface]{-\coneheight}{\conewidth}{-12}
   \conefront[surface]{-\coneheight}{\conewidth}{-12} 
  
   %\fill[violet!40!white,opacity=0.5] (-4,-4,0) -- (-4,4,0) -- (4,4,0) -- (4,-4,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) {};
   \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) {};
   \coneback[surface]{\coneheight}{\conewidth}{12}
   \conefront[surface]{\coneheight}{\conewidth}{12}

    % Draw the sphere
    \newcommand{\sphereradius}{2cm}
    \draw (0,0) circle (\sphereradius);
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (\sphereradius);

    % Draw the dashed arcs for the intersection with the cone
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5,0) arc (180:360:1.5cm and 0.5cm); % Adjusted for intersection
    \draw[dashed] (-1.5,0) arc (180:0:1.5cm and 0.5cm); % Adjusted for intersection
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Fiber of a unit sphere bundle on $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$}
 \label{cone}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz absolutely, thanks for pointing out!

Thanks for editing!

I changed your code a bit to add what you are looking for. I don't typically draw 3D images in this style, but after thinking about it I realized that I do like what it has to offer. For example, it would be impossible to draw it by little rectangles because the intersection would be jagged.
To find the intersection arcs, we can use a simple trick:

Take the upper-terminal point in the xz plane on the cone.

reciprocate each coordinate component of this point by the distance from that point to the origin (this turns it into a unit vector)

take the arcsin of the z-component of this unit vector to obtain the angle of elevation

graph the latitudinal line associated with that angle of elevation. (we can break it up into front and back using the azimuthal angle)



\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\tikzset{surface/.style={draw=blue!70!black, fill=blue!20!white, fill opacity=.6}}

\newcommand{\conewidth}{1.3}
\newcommand{\coneheight}{2.5}
\newcommand{\halfLength}{sqrt((\conewidth/2)^2+(\coneheight/2)^2)} % added
\newcommand{\angleOfElevation}{asin((\coneheight/2)/\halfLength)} % added
\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)} % added
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)} % added
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)} % added

\newcommand{\sphereradius}{2}

\newcommand{\coneback}[4][]{
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] 
    (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:225+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
}
\newcommand{\conefront}[4][]{
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] 
    (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:-135+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
}

\newcommand{\polar}{80}
\newcommand{\azimuth}{45}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\polar}{\azimuth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coneback[surface]{-\coneheight}{\conewidth}{-12}
\conefront[surface]{-\coneheight}{\conewidth}{-12} 

%\fill[violet!40!white,opacity=0.5] (-4,-4,0) -- (-4,4,0) -- (4,4,0) -- (4,-4,0) -- cycle;
\draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) {};
\draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) {};
\coneback[surface]{\coneheight}{\conewidth}{12}
\conefront[surface]{\coneheight}{\conewidth}{12}


\draw[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle (\sphereradius); % changed coordinate system
\shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle (\sphereradius);


% top
\draw[red,variable=\Vt,dashed, domain=\azimuth:\azimuth+180] plot ({\sphereradius*\sphereX{\Vt}{\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereY{\Vt}{\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereZ{\Vt}{\angleOfElevation}});
\draw[red,variable=\Vt, domain=\azimuth:\azimuth-180] plot ({\sphereradius*\sphereX{\Vt}{\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereY{\Vt}{\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereZ{\Vt}{\angleOfElevation}});



% bottom
\draw[red,variable=\Vt,dashed, domain=\azimuth:\azimuth+180] plot ({\sphereradius*\sphereX{\Vt}{-\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereY{\Vt}{-\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereZ{\Vt}{-\angleOfElevation}});
\draw[red,variable=\Vt, domain=\azimuth:\azimuth-180] plot ({\sphereradius*\sphereX{\Vt}{-\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereY{\Vt}{-\angleOfElevation}},{\sphereradius*\sphereZ{\Vt}{-\angleOfElevation}});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This is amazing, thanks! Just a short question: what do you mean by "I don't typically draw 3D images in this style"? Do you use a particular package?

@qarabala I usually draw them so the surfaces are opaque is what I meant. I see merit to making them translucent though, like in this one, because it lets you describe things that are going on behind surfaces.
